# Scala AmazonS3 unitest

Tags: scala, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mockito

I have a test that I have to change due to a change that I did in an S3Repository class
to use putObject method. I had to change the client from the type of **AmazonS3Client** that is deprecated to **AmazonS3**. That's how I did it:
The method is ***uploadCsvToS3***:

```
val creds = DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()
val awsRegion: Regions = Regions.fromName(configuration.get[String]("aws.s3.region"))
val client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(awsRegion).withCredentials(creds).build()
val fileName = produceFileNameForVersion(params_to_this_method)
client.putObject(AWSS3Bucket, fileName, file.toFile)
```

I know that the solution works, but there is a test that is not working:
I have a mock and override:

```
val client = mock[AmazonS3]
override def fakeApplication(): Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .overrides(bind[AmazonS3].toInstance(client))
```

and This is the test (positive case):

```
Mockito.when(client.putObject(MockitoMatchers.eq(s3Bucket), MockitoMatchers.anyString(), MockitoMatchers.eq(file))) thenReturn new PutObjectResult
val s3Repository : S3Repository = app.injector.instanceOf[S3Repository]
val s3Location = s3Repository.uploadCsvToS3(file.toPath).futureValue
assert(s3Location.fileName.nonEmpty)
```

I get this error:

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID:...
```

I tried a lot of solutions like configuration of access and secret key, PowerMockito and others.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT - Solution:
I found that this method is not testable because there is an instantiation of a client, but the purpose is to mock the client in order to test this method.
The solution was to create a Provider - AmazonS3ClientProvider, and override the method get. There, the client will be instantiate the same way. Then:

```
bind(classOf[AmazonS3]).toProvider(classOf[AmazonS3ClientProvider])
```

Comment: Your problem has to do with minute details of your actual code. There is no way to use mocking with the code which you provided. Can you share the exact relevant code which you want to test ?

Comment: The first section of the code is what I want to test. The method called uploadCsvToS3 (which is in the test below).

Comment: Then your method is pretty much un-testable.

Comment: I edit the file with the solution for this un-testable method.